# d3.js v4 drag and drop, collapsible tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Does anyone know how to build, or has anyone seen a DND and Collapsible Tree (denododiagram) for v4 or v5 of d3.js? Here's a great example with v3:
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762

There are plenty of examples of static trees, but I haven't been able to update this code to v4 successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example D3.js v4/v5 tree, hope it helps https://wizardace.com/d3-collapsible-tree/